# List and Sub-list align with n number column automatically

Tags: enumitem

I have using `enumitem` package for list alignment. How do split the `list` in `2 columns` or 3 or 4 columns (i.e. upto textwidth) and how do `align list` with `sublist` as per below image:

[image]

My MWE is:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item right 2 places
\item left 1 place
\item right 6 places
\item no change
\item left 3 places
\item right 3 places
\item right 1 place
\item left 7 places
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

This can be achieved using the `multicol` package.

```
\begin{multicols}{2}

\end{multicols}
```

around the outer enumeration or the second enumeration list will provide two columns.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}

\begin{multicols}{2}
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item
\begin{enumerate}
\item right 2 places
\item left 1 place
\item right 6 places
\item no change
\item left 3 places
\item right 3 places
\item right 1 place
\item left 7 places
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: how to automaticaly split columns upto textwidth. I have more than 200 question and answer expect automation like begin{enumerate}{3} or begin{enumerate}{5} etc...

Comment: @Balaji: Your question did not say anything about `automatical`

Comment: sorry, i have updated my question